# Excel html table export

Tags: php, html, excel, header, html-table

So I have this code:

```
$output = '
<table class="sticky-enabled">
 <thead><tr><th>Text0</th><th>Text1</th><th>Text2</th> </tr></thead>
<tbody id="">
 <tr class="odd"><td>7</td><td>texttt</td><td>texttt</td> </tr>
</table>';



    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel;");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.xls");
    print chr(255) . chr(254) . mb_convert_encoding($output, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
    exit;
```

And the thing would download an Excel file with the table.

There are 2 problems though:

1. When I open it with Excel it'll display the file you're trying to open is in different format from the extension error
2. When I try to save it, the default file extension is .htm instead of xls

Is there a way to manipulate the headers etc so that these 2 problems are resolved?

Comment: Easiest answer is to create a genuine BIFF Excel file using PHPExcel or one of the many other libraries for PHP that can do this; then you wouldn't have to screw-up your output with kludgy encoding changes either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
header('Content-type : text/csv');
```

and print it as a Comma separated value file. You can't just print an HTML table into an .xls or .xlsx